# Launch 2 browsers in kiosk mode on 2 display screens

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, chromium, kiosk-mode

im trying all sorts of things but i still cant get it working,

i need to launch 2 browsers (chrome or IE for that matter) displaying 2 different URLs. 
both should be running in kiosk mode and i need each to open on a designated screen (primary, secondary)

i've tried all kinds of combination using the commands in a BAT file or in a small JAR file yet i got none working.

what would be the best way to achieve that
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome takes command line flags to set the window position

```
--window-position
```

I'm not super proficient with BAT files but I believe if you have two lines that launch chrome with the appropriate flags and window position, it should achieve what you're looking for. Something like this (untested):

```
@echo off
start "Chrome" chrome --kiosk https://firsturl.com --window-position=x,y
start "Chrome" chrome --kiosk https://secondurl.com --window-position=x,y
```

Read more about --window-position here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-position

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a windows manager like i3.